# mmenu closes (on mobile) when input field in menu is interacted with

Tags: javascript, mmenu

This doesn't happen on desktop browsers so far from my testing, yet if I go to this website on an up to date Android device, the menu will close when I click into the 'location or postcode' box.

[image: input box in mmenu that closes the menu when its interacted with]

You can see the issue here: https://www.flyingbutler.com/

I thought that maybe setting onClick:{close:false} may have some effect on the issue but it doesn't. Can anyone assist ?

Comment: Cannot reproduce the issue.

Comment: What mobile platform did you use?   I've seen this on Android for sure.

Comment: Tried on samsung internet. Can't see any issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I upgraded to the v9 codebase of mmenu and that did indeed resolve the problem.  It wasn't what I really wanted to do as it required some other work to make the menu function exactly as before, but it did however resolve the issue this question was raised about.